# Adding Report watching makes the Ant tests really slow

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-6

We are using TeamCity 6.0.2 and have a build configuration that runs SoapUI tests. The tests themselves run in approx. 45 seconds when running in command line.

To see the results of the test, we use `Ant JUNit` report watcher with this `Report paths` value:

```
TestSoapUI\SoapUI-testresults\TEST-*.xml
```

And then the tests are taking up to 15 minutes, with a CPU at 100%.

What can we do to reduce this time? Other report path? Separate the test step from the report step?

(We also filed an issue to JetBrains, if you're interested: 
http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-16404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by the JetBrains team:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-16404

Upgrade to TeamCity 6.0.3 if you have the same problem.